# Qt passing QString to struct constructor doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I've got the following struct :

```
struct HidItem
{
    HidItem(){}
    HidItem(QString commandName, uint commandValue)
    {
        name = commandName;
        value = commandValue;
    }

    QString name;
    uint value;
};
```

and trying to create an instance like so:

```
HidCommandModel::HidCommandModel()
    : QAbstractListModel(),
      hidData(new QVector<HidItem>(10))
{
    HidItem *hidItem = new HidItem("USAGE_PAGE", 1);
    hidData->append(*(hidItem));
}
```

This isn't working too well, as only the **uint commandValue** gets assigned to the HidItem instance, and not the **QString "USAGE_PAGE"**

I haven't coded C++ in quite a few years, but this seems to me that I'm passing the string incorrectly, and needs to have some kung fu involved with pass by reference, pointers and copy and write.

The theory is there, but my practical skills are letting me down horribly today. Can anyone assist?

Comment: How do you check that it's not working?

Comment: I check by setting breakpoints in the code and inspecting the variables in a debug run.

Comment: Ok, problem isn't with the hidData->append line...

Comment: Unrelated to this particular problem, but you might want to fix that memory leak; you're unnecessarily creating the object with `new`, copying it, and then discarding the pointer. Try `hidData->append(HidItem("USAGE_PAGE, 1))` instead.

Comment: Cool, I'll do that, thanks Mike!

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk: Also, `hidData` should probably be a `QVector` object, not a pointer. It's best to avoid `new` unless you really need it.

Comment: Thanks Mike, did that too. I have a lot of brushing up to do. I think the last time I used C++ was in 2003. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

```
struct HidItem
{
    HidItem(){}
    HidItem(QString commandName, uint commandValue)
    {
        name = commandName;
        value = commandValue;
    }

    QString name;
    uint value;
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    HidItem *hidItem = new HidItem("USAGE_PAGE", 1);
    qDebug() << hidItem->name << "," << hidItem->value;
}
```

Output:

```
"USAGE_PAGE" , 1
```

One thing you should change is the signature of the `HidItem` constructor, so that it expects a const reference instead of an object:

```
HidItem(const QString& commandName, uint commandValue) {
...
```

This avoids unnecessary creation of temporary objects. But still, your approach also works well.

---

The real issue is the wrong usage of the QVector constructor:

```
QVector<HidItem>* hidData = new QVector<HidItem>(10);
hidData->append(hidItem);
```

appends the hidItem as element #11, since the `QVector` already contains 10 elements after being created.

Simply use

```
QVector<HidItem>* hidData = new QVector<HidItem>();
hidData->append(hidItem);
```

(and consider the remarks regarding `new` by @Mike Seymour).

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I just realised my problem is with the hidData->append(*(hidItem)); line. When I try to fetch the data by using hidData->at(0).name for example, I get nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the qDebug() tip, didn't know you could do that. ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks! My C++ has not only rusted over the years, I think I got mould growing all over it...:D

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk No issue - did you do Java coding recently? The `java.util.Vector` API behaves like you expected in your code ;-)

Comment: I did Java a few months ago on a project I was working, yes, but don't exactly recall using Vector that much. I do remember using other collection classes.